# Wildcard in join

Tags: r, data.table

This might be a stupid idea, but let me ask it anyways...

I'm facing the following problem. I'd like to join DT A on DT B.

```
A<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6), key="a,b")
B<-data.table(a=c(NA, 3, 3), b=c(6, NA, 6), c=c(5,6,7), key="a,b")

B[A, mult="first"]

   a b  c
1: 1 4 NA
2: 2 5 NA
3: 3 6  7
```

gives the result I am expecting. But is there a way to have wildcards (in the example I placed NA for the wildcards, it could have used "*" as well) in a join.

In the above example I'd expect:

```
   a b  c
1: 1 4 NA
2: 2 5 NA
3: 3 6  6
```

This is, because the second row of B "accepts" all values of column b in table A.

Is there a nice way to get the desired result?

**Edit:**
After thinking about this problem for quite some time without a satisfying result I'd be grateful for some ideas. For that, let me explain the situation a bit broader than above:
I'd like to classify people into groups. A person should be classified into the first group whose requirements it fullfills. Not all groups do ask for the same properties of a person. When the group does not have a requirement for a certain characteristic all values are allowed.

[image: The image below shows an example]

Any suggestions (does not have to involve data.tables) are much appreciated.

**edit2:**
I finally solved it like this, including wildcard-support, feel free to point me to improvements

```
classification<-list(
  list(
    list("Michael", "Thomas"), list("Brown"), list("*"), list("A")
  ), 
  list(
    list("*"), list("Red"), list(15, 16, 17, 18), list("B")
  ),
  list(
    list("Theresa"), list("Red"), list("*"), list("C")
  ),
  list(
    list("*"), list("Blond"), list("*"), list("D")
  ),
  list(
    list("*"), list("*"), list("*"), list("E")
  )  
)


participants<-data.table(name=c("Thomas", "Michael", "Sebastian", "Theresa", "Phil"), 
                         hair=c("Brown", "Blond", "Black", "Red", "Grey"),
                         age=c(15, 25, 15, 16, 15))


configToMappingTable<-function(config, dt){

  for(col in 1:(length(config[[1]])-1)){
    colVal<-unique(unlist(dt[, col, with=F]));  

    for(row in 1:length(config)){      
      config[[row]][[col]]<-lapply(config[[row]][[col]], glob2rx);
      config[[row]][[col]]<-unlist(lapply(config[[row]][[col]], function(x) as.list(colVal[grep(x, colVal)])), recursive=F);  
    }
  }

  res<-rbindlist(lapply(config, function(x) do.call(CJ, x)));
  res<-res[, lapply(.SD, as.character)];

  return(res[!duplicated(res[, 1:(ncol(res)-1), with=F])]);
}

mapping<-configToMappingTable(classification, participants)
setnames(mapping, c("name", "hair", "age", "group"))
mapping[, age:=as.numeric(age)]

setkey(participants, name, hair, age);
setkey(mapping, name, hair, age);
participants[mapping, group:=i.group]
```

Comment: do you mean that in cases where you have a multi-column key you are looking to join solely on the first column when the second column is NA valued?

Comment: Yes, and vice versa (only first key, if second is empty). But shouldn't be limited to just 2 key columns.

Comment: Perhaps `setkey(B,a)[A, mult='first'][,b:= i.b][, i.b:= NULL]`

Comment: fill-in your NA's with all possible values (making a larger table), then do a regular join